# Firefox eventsource doesn't connect

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an EventSource in javascript and a server side Rails Controller that streams SSE. This code works as intended in Chromium but not all in Firefox, there is no connection to the Server to request SSE in Firebug Connection Log and no attempt to connect in the Rails log and no console output in Firefox.

The Javascript looks like this:

```js
var ev = new EventSource('/stream/house-37-carts')
ev.onopen = function() { console.log('open') }
ev.onmessage = function() { console.log(arguments) }
ev.onerror = function() { console.log('error') }
```

The rails Controller:

```ruby
class StreamController < ApplicationController
include ActionController::Live

def index
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
  response.headers['Content-Length'] = '-1'
  response.headers['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'identity'
    sse = SSE.new response.stream, retry: 300

  begin
    ticker = Thread.new { loop { sse.write 0; sleep 5 } }
    sender = Thread.new do
      redis.subscribe params[:channel] do |on|
        on.message do |event, message|
          message = JSON.parse message
          sse.write(message['data'], :event => message['channel'])
        end
      end
    end
    ticker.join
    sender.join
  rescue IOError
  ensure
    Thread.kill(ticker) if ticker
    Thread.kill(sender) if sender
    sse.close
  end

end

end
```

The rails server (4.2.0) runs at http://localhost:3000 and runs puma. The javascript code is not wrapped into anything, just `<script type='text/javascript'> ... </script>`.